# Login Form and Log out button in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I would like to add a login form in Django Rest Framework. I am new to Django.

**First How to add a logout menu item in the Django rest framework?**

Eg.

[image]

I would like logout like this but my API does not menu item like=>

[image]

How to add that menu item?

**Second: How to add login form in Django rest framework?**

I take example from this => [HTML & Form](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/)

Here is my base project urls.py=>

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='rest_framework/login.html'), include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'), name='login'),
    # url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView, name='logout'),


    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),
]
```

I got this error

> cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

this is my login.html=>

```
{% extends "rest_framework/login_base.html" %} {% block branding %}
<h3 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">My Site Name</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

For both cases, All I need to do is to add this route to project urls.py

```
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

This route will allow me to log out of the user and will show the default login form.

reference => [Urls](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls)